# Refer to current row in window function

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Is it possible to refer to the current row in a window partition? I want to do something like the following:

`SELECT min(ABS(variable - CURRENT.variable)) over (order by criterion RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`

That is, i want to find in the given partition the variable which is closest to the current value. Is is possible to do something like that?

As an example, from:

`criterion | variable
  1  2
  2  4
  3  2
  4  7
  5  6`

We would obtain:

`null
  2
  0
  3
  1`

Thanks

Comment: Please can you post sample data and desired output? (text, not images please)

Comment: Wouldn't that always be 0, because the current value is in the partition?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you are absolutely right, I've edited accordingly. Right now it is even less feasible. Maybe it would be possible to do the min over the usual window function and filter later.

Comment: @etsa I've posted an example

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim: posted a solution (I hope so...)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this cannot be done with window functions.

But it can be done with a self join:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.variable,
       min(abs(a.variable - b.variable))
FROM mydata a
   LEFT JOIN mydata b
      ON (b.criterion < a.criterion)
GROUP BY a.id, a.variable
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
with t (v) as (values (-5),(-2),(0),(1),(3),(10))
select v,
    least(
        v - lag(v) over (order by v),
        lead(v) over (order by v) - v
    ) as closest
from t
;
 v  | closest                                                                                                          
----+---------                                                                                                         
 -5 |       3                                                                                                          
 -2 |       2                                                                                                          
  0 |       1
  1 |       1
  3 |       2
 10 |       7
```

Comment: You are only comparing two values with least, not all the previous

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim Since they are ordered the comparison is between the two closest.

Comment: They are not ordered by variable, but by another different criterion

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim Post sample data and desired output.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim: posted a solution (but test it, please)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help you (pay attention for performance problems).
I tried this in MSSQL (at bottom you'll find POSTGRESQL version):

```
CREATE TABLE TX (CRITERION INT, VARIABILE INT);
INSERT INTO TX VALUES (1,2), (2,4),(3,2),(4,7), (5,6);

SELECT CRITERION, MIN_DELTA FROM 
(
SELECT TX.CRITERION 
, MIN(ABS(B.TX2_VAR - TX.VARIABILE)) OVER (PARTITION BY TX.CRITERION) AS MIN_DELTA
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TX.CRITERION ORDER BY ABS(B.TX2_VAR - TX.VARIABILE) ) AS MIN_RANK
FROM TX
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TX2.CRITERION AS TX2_CRIT, TX2.VARIABILE AS TX2_VAR FROM TX TX2 WHERE TX2.CRITERION < TX.CRITERION) B
) C
WHERE MIN_RANK=1
ORDER BY CRITERION 
;
```

Output:

```
CRITERION   MIN_DELTA
----------- -----------
2           2
3           0
4           3
5           1
```

POSTGRESQL Version (tested on Rextester  http://rextester.com/VMGJ87600):

```
CREATE TABLE TX (CRITERION INT, VARIABILE INT);
INSERT INTO TX VALUES (1,2), (2,4),(3,2),(4,7), (5,6);
SELECT * FROM TX;

SELECT CRITERION, MIN_DELTA FROM 
(
SELECT TX.CRITERION 
, MIN(ABS(B.TX2_VAR - TX.VARIABILE)) OVER (PARTITION BY TX.CRITERION) AS MIN_DELTA
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TX.CRITERION ORDER BY ABS(B.TX2_VAR - TX.VARIABILE) ) AS MIN_RANK
FROM TX
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (SELECT TX2.CRITERION AS TX2_CRIT, TX2.VARIABILE AS TX2_VAR FROM TX TX2 WHERE TX2.CRITERION < TX.CRITERION) B ON TRUE
) C
WHERE MIN_RANK=1
ORDER BY CRITERION 
;

DROP TABLE TX;
```

Output:

```
    criterion   variabile
1   1   2
2   2   4
3   3   2
4   4   7
5   5   6

    criterion   min_delta
1   1   NULL
2   2   2
3   3   0
4   4   3
5   5   1
```